# Hide http request header information in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, http

Could I hide some header information from http request? For example, I have this header in my http request X-MicrosoftAjax : (xxxxxx), would it be possible to hide this(xxxxxx) value?

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt your key with crypto algorithms. But in Asp.Net you can get header only in code. If you want higher security, use https.

Comment: Thanks a lot Zahidli , I want to use this with http, so I will try to encrypt the values.

Comment: i found it useful. this is worked for me

Comment: Do you have some way to encrypt the value of a request header?

Comment: You can use any crypto algorithm for this.